# how to add some key to all ajax calls in existing get/post requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i'm working on a existing big project where i have requirement like

**Question:** i need to add `auth_token` to all existing Apis of `GET` and `POST`  almost 1239 in count. how to intercept all `GET,POST` to add `auth_token`.

After intercepting and attaching `auth_token` all apis must have `auth_token` key

Here is how i need all apis to be called with auth_token

```js
var AUTH_TOKEN = '8450d1eaf4fe0daf6dd';

//code to intercept all ajax call to add auth_key into it


$.ajax({
   url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
   type:'GET',
   success:function(){
      console.log('sent url must contain auth_token',this.url);
   }
});


$.ajax({
   url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
   type:'POST',
   data:JSON.stringify({"userId":919,id:966,title:'a'}),
   success:function(){
      console.log('sent data must conatain auth_token',this.data);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `beforeSend` method of `$.ajaxSetup` to add data to all requests you send.

It's worth noting that even though the property is added, your API still returns an error stating that the `auth_token` is required. Check the API documentation to ensure that it doesn't need to be sent in the request in a different manner, as a header for example.

```js
var AUTH_TOKEN = '8450d1eaf4fe0daf6dd';

$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
    if (settings.type === 'GET') {
      settings.url += (settings.url.indexOf('?') == -1 ? '?' : '&') + 'auth_token=' + AUTH_TOKEN
    } else {
      let data = JSON.parse(settings.data || '{}');
      data.auth_token = AUTH_TOKEN;
      settings.data = JSON.stringify(data);
    }
  }
});

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
  type: 'GET',
  success: function() {
    console.log('sent url must contain auth_token', this.url);
  }
});


$.ajax({
  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
  type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify({
    "userId": 919,
    id: 966,
    title: 'a'
  }),
  success: function() {
    console.log('sent data must conatain auth_token', this.data);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i think for get it is not attached, for post it is working fine

Comment: expected for GET like this `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1?s={auth_token:'8450d1eaf4fe0daf6dd'}`

Comment: You're correct, I updated to dd the querystring parameter to the GET request

Comment: Wait, you want to send JSON in a querystring parameter...? That's a VERY odd thing to do

Comment: >>> Wait, you want to send JSON in a querystring parameter...

**NOT REQUIRED** working fine thanks alot